# Is there a REALLY simple way to use git - like one single command?

Tags: git, versioning

What I mean is:

- We have a server that stores the latest version,
- During my day, sometimes I want to commit my changes,
- After I committed all I've done, I want to get in sync with others,
- If no problems occured, I want to get back to work with no extra steps.

In a dreamworld, this *should be* done with just one command, like "git snap" and it should manage all the steps; of course when something goes wrong (a conflict that can't be auto-resolved) it would give me an error message and I'd start doing it the hard way.  (Yes I can do it, I'm using git every day, just want to make it effortless.)

**So, what's the simplest way** to achieve this?  A batch, perhaps?  A series of git commands like stash + pull + stashpop + commit, or commit + pull + push? Is there an automatic way to do this, in the optimist case when no bad conflicts happen?

I'm using git with 3 different clients now (SourceTree, GitExtensions, TortoiseGIT) but neither makes my life that simple. I don't want to stash manually all the time, I'm not interested in the detailed messages, just one command and it's either all done OR failed for a reason.

Is there a way?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your question is a bit like asking why is driving a stick shift so difficult?  Well, because it gives you fine-grain control over the engine at all times while driving.  If you don't like it, buy an automatic.

Comment: @Tim I think he's asking for the computer regulating the automatic in your analogy.

Comment: @Tim: Well, that's a non-answer.  I don't downvote it because you didn't - but my question was about a practical default way to simplify a complex process. It's no good to tell me it's flexible - I know, thanks.  There are systems that beat git in complexity and flexibility but still can give an easy way for the most likely situations.  The question makes sense.  Just ignore it if you don't agree.

Comment: Look into `git-up` or using a batch script.  Git's interface is actually very simple IMO, much easier than something like Perforce.

Comment: Git-up looks interesting but it's compiled for Mac.  Can't find a Windows version.

Comment: The trivial answer seems to be "just write a script that runs the Git commands that comprise your standard workflow".

Comment: Yes, it's quite trivial and of course I can write myself a script. Even with error handling. But, really - no tool like this?  No one ever had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option I can think of is a bash function or script to run the commands in series. My workflow would look like this (since you don't care about commit message):

```
git commit -a --allow-empty-message -m ''
git pull --rebase
git push
```

For me, this would capture probably 80% (SWAG) of my workflow. The `git pull --rebase` is the only step likely to fail. It will fail if there are any conflicts, but leave you in a position to correct then, then continue the rebase with `git rebase --continue`. From here, you would then `git push` to complete the workflow.

You might also look into GitHub's own Git client, it's quite simple and integrates well. However, it won't give you the "one click operation" you are searching for. https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: That's one good answer.  I'll try to implement something like this if no "one-click" alternative pops up.  The only reason I don't mark this as accepted right away is that I'd like to give others some time. Maybe someone already wrote the Magic Batch.

Answer (score 1):

This is one command:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit" && git pull --rebase && git push origin master
```

You can also have conflicts to resolve. This will get harder then.

**Please note that you're not using git the way it's supposed to be.**

Git shouldn't be used just to share code or to backup your work.

Comment: Thanks - yes I know, and as I wrote in the question, I'm using Git actively. I know what it's good at.  In particular, I mentioned the commit + pull + push which was my normal workflow too, until I discovered the auto-stash option in GitExtensions.  I don't want to misuse git - I want to make the simple case automatic, and only care about exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question! My life is easy since I am using git through PHPStorm. I suggest you to take a try with it. It handles these automatically, and it has code completion as well :P

Answer (score 0):

It can be a good way to use Makefile to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After a few months of trying different clients, I found that ***GitExtensions*** is what does the most for effortless syncing.  It has an "auto stash" option when you do a pull - automatically saving all your changes, then fetching new stuff from the server, then merging your own changes back on them (stash pop), all this without even touching it if you want.  It also gives you a way to solve conflicts manually (though you'll need a compare/merge tool for that, like TortoiseMerge).

TLDR: GitExt seems to be the answer to my prayers.